# Realy need some help with social sharing button

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, social-networking

I bump into this problem:

When you go to my website: http://www.appartementtekooputrecht.nl and click on the twitter share button, it directs twitter to http://www.appartementtekooputrecht.nl/samenvatting (last page) in stead of to the homepage.
I have placed the share plugin share code in more parts of the theme, but with no good result.

Fyi in this theme all pages are displayed on the homepage.

Any help would be realy appreciated!

here is my header.php (share is at the end)

```
<?php global $shortname; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php elegant_titles(); ?></title>
<?php elegant_description(); ?>
<?php elegant_keywords(); ?>
<?php elegant_canonical(); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Atom Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/ie6style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">DD_belatedPNG.fix('img.overlay, div#content-bg-bottom');</script>
<![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-bg-bottom">
            <div id="header">
                            <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" rel="resume">Home</a></li>
                    <?php query_posts(array
                                                ('post_type' => 'page',
                                                'orderby' => get_option('myresume_nav_sort_pages'),
                                                'order' => get_option('myresume_nav_order_page'),
                                                'post__not_in' => get_option('myresume_nav_exclude_pages')
                                                )); ?>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post()?>
                    <li><a href="#" rel="<?php echo($post->post_name) ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?> 
                </ul>
                     <br class="clear" />

                <div id="logo">
                    <img class="avatar" alt="Appartement te koop Utrecht Utrecht" src="http://www.tim-productions.tv/appartementtekooputrecht.nl/wp-content/themes/MyResume/images/appartement-te-koop-utrecht-logo.jpg" />
                   <img class="overlay" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/photo-overlay.png" alt="" />
                    <span>
                        <br />
                        <?php echo(get_option('myresume_email')) ?>

                        <br />
                        <?php echo(get_option('myresume_phone')) ?>
                    </span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="inside">
                <div id="inside-bg-top">
                    <div id="inside-bg-bottom">
                        <div class="resume slide">
                             <div class="social"><?php lacands_wp_filter_content_widget(); ?></div>
```

And here the theme index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>  
                        <?php query_posts(array
                                                ('post_type' => 'page',
                                                'orderby' => get_option('myresume_sort_pages'),
                                                'order' => get_option('myresume_order_page'),
                                                'post__in' => get_option('myresume_exclude_pages')
                                                )); ?>
                            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post()?>
                                <div class="page-content">
                                <div class="entry">
                                <?php the_content('') ?>
                                </div>
                                <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?> 


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Added the themes index.php and the header.php now. Please let me know if you need more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded that plugin and I can see in the code of the file "la-click-and-shared.php", around line 560, that the widget gets the links that passes to the social buttons from the permalink of the current post/page. What I can't know is why you have that permalink.

I would guess it must be a problem either with the permalink/name of the post, with the permalinks setting in general or with the AJAX functionality, but it is difficult to help you further without further details.

You could try these:

1. Check the permalink of that page or post you are showing as home.
2. Disable custom permalinks temporarily and see if it works then.
3. Is the Settings > Reading > Front page displays option set correctly?
4. Disable other plugins temporarily

**Edit:**
You could also edit la-click-and-shared.php. In the latest version that I just have downloaded, this is line 556:

```
$args['link'] = htmlentities($link1);
```

If you can't fix it any other way and/or you are in a hurry, you could just do:

```
$args['link'] = 'http://www.appartementtekooputrecht.nl';
```

Since your site only exposes that URL anyway it is not a big deal. But, of course, you are 'breaking' the plugin if you change your site in the future so it doesn't use AJAX (inappropriately in my opinion) to load all the pages with the same URL (no browsing history either).